# Write HTML and JQuery to via C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write a C# class that will return various code pieces to a view in MVC4. The code I am returning has both html and jquery in it. Currently I am doing the following:

```
output += "<table id =\"" + grid.name + "\"></table>\n";
output += "<div id=\"" + grid.pager + "\"></div>\n";
output += "jQuery(\"" + grid.name + "\") //and so on
```

This is my method. Output is a string. This string contains both html and jquery. I am simply returning output:

```
return output;
```

Then, in my view I am using @Html.Raw to convert the string:

```
@Html.Raw(MyMethod.GetString())
```

The problem is that the html elements a formatted correctly but the jquery elements are written to the page as plain text. Any ideas how I can get the page to turn the string into actual syntax? Should I return my string differently?

Comment: hmm, I think the problem is that I forgot script tags. Let me try that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jquery is javascript, you should wrap this code in a `<script>` tag:

```
output += "<table id =\"" + grid.name + "\"></table>\n";
output += "<div id=\"" + grid.pager + "\"></div>\n";
output += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">jQuery(\"" + grid.name + "\");</script> //and so on
```